# Ray Cast Collision Detection Missing

Tags: floating-point, collision-detection, precision, box2d

I am writing my own Ray Cast collision detector and every now and then, like one in a million times (which ends up being quite frequent). I get a ray that just manages to slip through the gaps between two sides of a polygon due to rounding point errors. It is really annoying and I do not know how to solve this problem at all. Not only that but it seems that the creators of [Box2D](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082976) have the same problem:

> Caution
>
> Due to round-off errors, ray casts can sneak through small cracks between polygons in your
>   static environment. If this is not acceptable in your application, please enlarge your 
>   polygons slightly.

So, to those that have actually done this before, how do I make sure that I never suffer this type of rounding point error with floating point values? What workarounds have you used so that this problem does not affect your program ever.

P.S. I have read a large amount about floating point numbers and I still cannot figure out how to make the one in a million problem go away. There must be something I am missing.

Comment: You can't make sure you never have this problem with floating point values...and isn't a potential solution given to you right there?

Comment: @Bart: Okay so no possible general solution, but does it literally mean just enlarge my polygons? Won't that just move the problem to a different location on the screen?

Comment: You're doing collision detection? If you have a lot of detail in your collision geometry, you could try to simplify the geometry a bit, having large triangles. And you could let the edges overlap ever so slightly. If it's collision geometry it won't be rendered anyway.

Comment: @Bart: Unfortunately for the type of game that I am making the collision geometry has a very close relationship to the geometry of the objects that it represents. I cannot just reduce the detail for it would make things weird.

Comment: Then just go for the overlapping triangles and see how that works out for you

Comment: If the Box2D manual was talking about cracks between faces of a polygon, you would be correct that making polygons larger would not help anything. However there is a big difference between slipping through the cracks _between polygons_, and cracks _between two sides_ of one polygon. I doubt the Box2D implementation has any slipping between two faces of one polygon, you might want to check again how he does it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is due to the approximate nature of floating-point numbers. What many programmers do in this situation is to try to compare their computed result against their desired test (or in your case, evaluating the distance between the cast ray and the polygon), and then determinig if this difference is less than some epsilon value. THIS IS THE WRONG APPROACH.

I *strongly* encourage you to read Bruce Dawson's article on [Comparing Floating Point Numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/Comparing%20floating%20point%20numbers.htm). This is the solution you're looking for.

By the way, "enlarging your polygons slightly" is equivalent to using an epsilon value, and won't work if you can't guarantee the domain of the sizes and positions of all polygons in your world.